# loop through a list of properties

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, properties

I got following problem.
I have a view properties in my class which access a config and can raise a `ValueError` if the user added garbage to the config.

I would like to write a method to check my config-file for errors, so I thought I look through every property in a list and try to access its value. Therefore I would not need to duplicate the `try-except` for every property.

I tried the following code, which - of course - calls the properties when creating the list and therefore throws the error outside my try.
Is there an elegant solution to my problem?

```
import random


def load_config():
    rand_number = random.randint(0, 9)
    if rand_number == 5:
        raise ValueError

    return rand_number


class foo:
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return load_config()

    @property
    def bar2(self):
        return load_config()

    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return load_config()

    @property
    def bar4(self):
        return load_config()

    @property
    def bar5(self):
        return load_config()


    def check_properties(self):
        properties = [
            self.bar1, //Exceptions are thrown here
            self.bar2,
            self.bar3,
            self.bar4,
            self.bar5,
        ]

        for property in properties:
            try:
                num = property
            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError at " + property.__name__)

my_foo = foo()
my_foo.check_properties()
```

To make an mve I replaced the property-bodies with a call to a function with creates a random `ValueError`

Comment: You could store the name and use `getattr(self, property_name)` instead.

Comment: @karthikr: That's normal. I don't think you read the question correctly.

Comment: @VincentSavard How can I extract the name of a property? __name__ does not seem to work with properties

Comment: `num = getattr(self, "bar1")`. etc... would do the trick.

Comment: @tdelaney Yepp, its pretty much the same as VincentSavard said and it works, but a solution without string-literals would be great.

Comment: @Altoyyr: You could get all property names by doing something like `[property_name for property_name, obj in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if isinstance(obj, property)]`. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @VincentSavard That could be risky... it assumes that all properties should be touched when some may not be related to the config. Suppose the class also had a property called `large_calculation_you_dont_want_to_do_often`?

Comment: @tdelaney: Of course it could, but unless you want to type all your properties by hand, there aren't many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `check_properties` with something like this:

```
def check_properties(self):
        properties = [property_name for property_name, obj in self.__class__.__dict__.items() 
                          if isinstance(obj, property)]

        for property_name in properties:
            try:
                getattr(self, property_name)
            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError at " + property_name)
```

It will attempt to evaluate the property in `getattr`.

This will not work for properties inherited by the base class. You could use a helper function like this instead if you use inheritance:

```
def get_property_names(cls, follow_inheritance=False):
    property_names = []

    for attr_name, attr in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(attr, property):
            property_names.append(attr_name)

    if follow_inheritance:
        for parent_class in cls.__mro__:
            if parent_class != cls:
                property_names.extend(get_property_names(parent_class, True))

    return property_names
```

then define `check_properties` as:

```
def check_properties(self):
        properties = get_property_names(self.__class__, follow_inheritance=True)

        for property_name in properties:
            try:
                getattr(self, property_name)
            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError at " + property_name)
```

Comment: Just to wave a red flag for others who pass this way, this solution is risky because it assumes all properties should be called. Don't use if you have other properties that do calculations that you don't want performed during a check. It also doesn't check class parents so it would have to be updated if you use class inheritance.

Comment: @tdelaney: I assume people know the risk since the question is literally "How can I evaluate all the properties in an object?". Your point about inheritance is valid though.

Comment: Definitely a valid point,  this works nice in my case, but may be super risky in other situations.